# using lm() in R for a series of independent fits

Tags: r, lm

I want to use `lm()` in R to fit a series (actually 93) separate linear regressions.  According to the R `lm()` help manual:

*"If response is a matrix a linear model is fitted separately by least-squares to each column of the matrix."*

This works fine as long as there are no missing data points in the Y response matrix.  When there are missing points, instead of fitting each regression with the available data, every row that has a missing data point in any column is discarded.  Is there any way to specify that `lm()` should fit all of the columns in Y independently and not discard rows where an individual column has a missing data point?

Comment: Why not some variation of `sapply(1:93, function(j) lm(y[,j]~x)`

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to do `n` regressions between `Y1, Y2, ..., Yn` and `X`, you don't specify that with `lm()` rather you should use R's [apply functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega):

```
# create the response matrix and set some random values to NA
values <- runif(50)
values[sample(1:length(values), 10)] <- NA
Y <- data.frame(matrix(values, ncol=5))
colnames(Y) <- paste0("Y", 1:5)
# single regression term
X <- runif(10)

# create regression between each column in Y and X
lms <- lapply(colnames(Y), function(y) {
  form <- paste0(y, " ~ X")
  lm(form, data=Y)
})

# lms is a list of lm objects, can access them via [[]] operator
# or work with it using apply functions once again
sapply(lms, function(x) {
  summary(x)$adj.r.squared
})
#[1] -0.06350560 -0.14319796  0.36319518 -0.16393125  0.04843368
```

Comment: Andy, Thanks for the detailed answer.  I tried your approach and it worked great.  Bob